# Load MIB using SNMP4J

Tags: java, mib, snmp4j

I am totally new to mib and i have read about snmp on [techdive](http://techdive.in/snmp/beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-snmp-simple-network-management-protocol) and get the basic understanding of SNMP4J can anyone tell me how to use MIB in snmp4j ?
Thank in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. You basically query a client for information giving an OID for the field in the MIB you require.

A basic sample taken from the referenced blog is:

```
PDU request = new PDU();
request.setType(PDU.GET);
OID oid= new OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0");
request.add(new VariableBinding(oid));
```

The reference you can use:
http://www.jineshmathew.com/2012/11/how-to-get-started-with-snmp4j.html

Here is another reference:
http://www.jayway.com/2010/05/21/introduction-to-snmp4j/

Here is the java doc for the OID: http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/smi/OID.html

Comment: That was really helpfull @Kevin Bayes

Answer (score -1):

you need to register your MIB using snmp4j.

```
   final OID interfacesTable = new OID(".1.3.6.1.4.1.44.1");
        MOTableBuilder builder = new MOTableBuilder(interfacesTable)
        .addColumnType(SMIConstants.SYNTAX_OCTET_STRING,MOAccessImpl.ACCESS_READ_WRITE)
        //first row
        .addRowValue(new OctetString("loopback"))
        //next row
        .addRowValue(new Integer32(4));
        agent.registerManagedObject(builder.build());
        agent.listen();
```

Comment: MOTableBuilder is not part of SNMP4J-Agent. The example does not define the mandatory MOTableIndex for the table.